# Django and services

Tags: django, service

I'm building a simple website with django that requires constant monitoring of text-based data from another website, that's the way it have to be.

How could I run this service on my web-host using django? would I have to start a separate app and run it via SSH, so it updates the database used by django, or are there any easier/better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to celery, you could also create a cron job that executes a [custom django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). That would give you full access to your django install and ORM. The downside is that cron's smallest time resolution is 1 minute, so if you need it to be real-time, you're not going to be able to do that.

If you do need realtime, then creating a [python daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) might be a better option.

Comment: If he's hitting a site and parsing text off of it more than once a minute he's probably going to get ban hammered by any half awake admin.

Comment: No John, I'll have enough time between hits, and there's no captcha.

Comment: @John: if the admin cares about a few hits a minute, they're probably running the world's smallest site or the worst-performing architecture. I can serve 1,000 req/s without a blink on a tiny little VPS, to put that in perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html) to schedule a job that would read data from that other website and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: It' nice to know this library, it'll be useful in another app of mine, but using just django is a better alternative to me.